# Javascript for loop not behaving as I expected

Tags: javascript

So the code is very straight forward, don't worry about `isPrime` function. In my `findPrime` function I set my iterator: `primeCnt = 0`. I then enter a for loop where my condition is `primeCnt <= max` where `max = 10001`. `i` in my for loop is NOT the iterator. I use `i` to generate prime numbers.

My for ends with `primeCnt == 10002` but the for should exit when `primeCnt = 10001`. If I change my for condition to `primeCnt < max` I get the expected results I need but the for condition should be `primeCnt <= max`.

**UPDATE**

It's just a regular old for loop, I was just over thinking things, just like any iterator that starts at zero and you want to go to say string.length or max value, the exit will be = string.length when the for comparison is `<` and it will be one above string.length if you use `<=` comparison. It's just a good ole for loop and I was tired and over thinking it.

**What's wrong with my brain here or is there something different about when a for loop condition comparison instruction "fires" compared to C style languages like C# and C++**

```js
    function findPrime() {
        var max = 10001;
        var lastPrime = 0;
        var primeCnt = 0;

        for (var i = 0; primeCnt <= max; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                lastPrime = i;
                primeCnt++;
            }
           
        }
        console.log(primeCnt);
        return lastPrime;
    }

    function isPrime(value) {
        for (var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
            if (value % i === 0)
                return false;
        }

        return value > 1;
    }

    console.log(findPrime());
```

Comment: Of course `primeCnt == 10002`; that's why the loop exits. The last time it runs is when `primeCnt == 10001`, after which `primeCnt` is incremented one more time, the condition fails, and the loop ends. This, by the way, is the same way it works in languages like C++ and C#. JavaScript is also a "C-style language," even though it has obvious differences.

Comment: I guess I am just too tired but I am still enjoying the work so I on I toil. Its just like int i =0; i < string.length and I am too tired to realize that lol

Comment: You need `primeCnt <= max`. Then, change `max` to `10000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the very last iteration of your code, at the beginning your primeCnt is equal to 10001. At that point, it runs the block of code, part of which includes increasing primeCnt by 1. So, after the final iteration runs, your primeCnt is 10002.

Comment: Thank you, I am being silly for not seeing it, its just like any other for loop lol

Answer (score 1):

Of course primeCnt == 10002; that's why the loop exits. The last time it runs is when primeCnt == 10001, after which primeCnt is incremented one more time, the condition fails, and the loop ends. This, by the way, is the same way it works in languages like C++ and C#. JavaScript is also a "C-style language," even though it has obvious differences.

*I originally posted a version of this as a comment, but it's really an answer, so I'm posting it as one.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ed, I decided to give the points to phil as he has so little and you have an amazing amount, don't want the rich getting too richer now ;)

Comment: @BrianOgden Ha! Okay, well, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's explain your own code.

```
(var i = 0; primeCnt <= max; i++)
```

Equals to:

```
var i = 0;
if (primeCnt <= max)
{
    i++;
}
```

So, when `i=10001`, `10001 <= 10001`, which increments `i` to `10002`.

If you want the expression to be `<=`, just set the max as `10000`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't think you are following though

Comment: Sorry, following what?